# React Semantic-UI: Modal component with Form component? Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, semantic-ui-css

So, I'm trying to use Semantic UI modal component with the form component.

My problem is that if I use these two together the UI becomes bad.

I created a sandbox about my current situation: https://codesandbox.io/s/2n1pj96ry

As you can see now the **submit** button does not attached to the **form**. 
If I move the `Form` component directly inside the `Modal` component, like this:

`<Modal...>
 <Form>
     ...
 </Form>
</Modal>`

the **submit** will attached to the **form**, but the UI breakes down.

I tried to add different classes to these components (like `ui modal` to the `Form` component, but it doesnt worked well).

Do you have any suggetsion?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What a `type="submit"` button does is call the `onSubmit` handler attached to the form when it is clicked. You don't *have* to submit your form that way, you could also call the handler straight from the button with `onClick={this.submitHandler}` for example. That way, your button doesn't necessarily have to be a child of the form.

Comment: @Jaxx
Thanks, I didn't thought about this.

Basically I would like to solve this problem without calling the form submit method manually, but if I could not solve this problem with the "normal" way I will use your solution.

Comment: Unless you were planning to submit the form through 'traditional' HTML (meaning through a form action and a full page refresh), you will have to call your form handler manually anyway (or more accurately, define your own handler).

Comment: @Jaxx I would like to accept your suggestion, but I cant accept it. I think you should write your suggestion as a answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `as` prop on the Modal to make it a form element.

```
<Modal 
   as={Form} 
   onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}
   open={true}
   size="tiny">
```

Any button with the `submit` type in your modal will fire the onSubmit handler. I find this to be a nice way to opt-in to required fields and easy validation by the browser on form elements.

Be sure to pass the event to your submit handler and use the `preventDefault` method to avoid the browser from automatically trying to post your form.

Forked your sandbox and made a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/silly-hopper-v392m). The modal is changed to a `<form>` element, the Input has the `required` property and the browser will demand the element is valid before firing the `onSubmit` handler. The default form action is prevented, and you can handle as desired with whatever.

Comment: I wish I found your solution earlier. Wasted so much time on this, ended moving the submit button onto the modal footer field and hiding the button which already was there :D

Comment: Your solution is amazing. Thanks.

Comment: Whoaaaaaaaa. A thousand +'s sir!